# MockGeneratorClass Fails - Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method

Tags: apex

I can't figure out how to get the testclass to complete successfully, although both Trigger and Class are at 90% coverage.

IT Keeps failing with the following error:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, LeadMgmt_InsideSales: execution of AfterInsert

caused by: System.AsyncException: Future method cannot be called from a future or batch method: HTTPRequestSender_Class.sendHTTPRequest(String, String)

Trigger.LeadMgmt_InsideSales: line 20, column 1: []
```

Is the HTTPRequestSender_Test class even required here?

Trigger:

```
trigger LeadMgmt_InsideSales on Lead (after insert) {

ID[] ids = new List<ID>();
String url = 'https://inc1.insidesales.com/do=noauth/immediate_response';
String body;

for (Lead l : Trigger.new) {

    Group q = [Select id, name from Group where name = 'Inbound SDR Queue'];

    if (l.OwnerID == q.id) {
        ids.add(l.Id);
    }
}  

if (!ids.isEmpty()) {
   body = 'method=responsepop&inbound_initiative_id=60&ids='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(JSON.serialize(ids), 'ISO-8859-1');       
   HTTPRequestSender_Class.sendHTTPRequest(url, body);
  }
}
```

Class:

```
global class HTTPRequestSender_Class {
@future (callout=true)
Public static void sendHTTPRequest(String url, String body){

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setBody(body);
    req.setMethod('POST');

    try {
        res = http.send(req);
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        System.debug('CalloutException: '+ e);
        System.debug(res.toString());
    }
 }
}
```

TestClass:

```
 @isTest
 public class HTTPRequestSender_Test {
 @isTest static void testCallout() {
    // Set mock callout class 
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());      
    HttpResponse res = CalloutClass.getInfoFromExternalService();

  }
}
```

Callout Class

```
public class CalloutClass {
public static HttpResponse getInfoFromExternalService() {
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('https://inc1.insidesales.com/do=noauth/immediate_response');
    req.setMethod('GET');
    Http h = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    return res;
  }
}
```

MockGeneratorClass:

```
@isTest(SeeAllData=true)
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
// Implement this interface method
global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

    Group q = [Select id, name from Group where name = 'Inbound SDR Queue'];

    Lead l = new Lead(LastName = 'Test', Company = 'ABC', Email = 'test@test.com', ownerid = q.Id);
    insert l;

    ID[] ids = new List<ID>();
    ids.add(l.Id);

 System.assertEquals('https://inc1.insidesales.com/do=noauth/immediate_response', req.getEndpoint());
    System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());

    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.setBody('method=responsepop&inbound_initiative_id=60&ids='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(JSON.serialize(ids), 'ISO-8859-1'));
    res.setStatusCode(200);
    return res;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestClass:

```
@isTest
public class HTTPRequestSender_Test {
//@isTest static void testCallout() {
public static testmethod void testCallout() {

    Group q = [Select id, name from Group where name = 'Queue'];
    Database.DMLOptions dml = new Database.DMLOptions();
    dml.DuplicateRuleHeader.AllowSave = true;        
    Lead l = new Lead(LastName = 'Test', Company = 'ABC', Email = 'test@test.com', ownerid = q.Id);
    l.setOptions(dml);

    Test.startTest();
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGeneratorIS_Test());        
    insert l;
    Test.stopTest();

    HttpResponse res = CalloutClass.getInfoFromExternalService();

    // Verify response received contains fake values
    String contentType = res.getHeader('Content-Type');
    System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
    String actualValue = res.getBody();
    String expectedValue = 'method=responsepop&inbound_initiative_id=213&ids='+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(JSON.serialize(l.Id), 'ISO-8859-1');
    System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
    System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());

}
}
```